# BottomNavigation Icons not shown

Tags: nativescript-vue

On a nativescript vue app, I added a BottomNavigation manually, here a part of the template:

```html
    <StackLayout>
            <BottomNavigation selectedIndex="0">
                <TabStrip>
                    <TabStripItem>
                        <Image src="font://&#xf1ea;" class="far"></Image>
                        <Label text="Start"></Label>
                    </TabStripItem>
                    <TabStripItem>
                        <Label text="Info"></Label>
                    </TabStripItem>                    
                </TabStrip>
                <TabContentItem>
```

Instead of showing an icon in the **BottomNavigation** above the text, there is a text like this: &#xf1ea.

If I try to follow the link to the source, it says unable to read file &#xf1ea.
Do I have to add a path to the fonts?

As I add the BottomNavigation manually, do I have to add something more?

Thanks for your hints.
Juergen

Comment: https://fontawesome.cc/ check this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a fontawesome font to your **fonts** folder then use it with a label.

```html
    <Label  text="" textWrap="true" class=" fas "fontSize="22" />
```

Label text attribute contains  [Private Use characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_Use_Areas)  click on icon it self, then copy it

```css
.fas {
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free", "fa-solid-900";
    font-weight: 900;
}
```

You can copy icons by directly clicking on images from  https://fontawesome.com/cheatsheet

Click on the icon itself, then copy it.

**Nativescript official docs:** https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/components/icon-fonts